# After upgrading to Angular 9, compile time has increased drastically

Tags: angular, angular8

When I upgraded from Angular 8 to 9, the compile time increased by more than 3 times and also, I used the Scss style template but after upgrading, when I generate component, it creates a css file for the component.

I checked angular.json and the config is "styleext": "scss" 
is there any solution for these issues?

Answer (score 4):

### Compile Time Issue

**FIX**

Turn off AOT in the **angular.json** -> search the first occurrence (default build config) of **aot** and change from *true* to ***false***

The production build should still use AOT, since the production build config further down has AOT still turned on.

**Explanation**

As part of migration from Angular 8 > 9 they simply decided to enable the AOT (Ahead Of Time) compilation not only for --prod builds, but also for regular builds (+watch/serve), with the argument that AOT is now much faster with the new Ivy compiler. They haven't thought this through IMO, because this caused my watch/serve builds to increase from 1 second to 30 seconds.

Further reading:
https://v9.angular.io/guide/ivy

### Style Extension Issue

The correct definition is through **style and not styleext**.
Create a new project (`ng new demo`) and choose SCSS and have a look how it is defined there.

Comment: Good catch man !!! I had exactly the same problem, the serving went from 2 sec to 16 after update 8->9, this is now much better. This should be the accepted answer !

Answer (score 3):

I got same issue when I migrated Angular 4 to Angular 9. Then, I disabled `Ivy` in Angular 9. From Angular 9, `Ivy` is set to `true` as default which was not in Angular 8.

Go to `tsconfig.json` and disabled `Ivy` mode.

```
{
  ...
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableIvy": false
  }
  ...
}
```

Note: This is temporary solution only. Maybe, in the next version, this issue will be handled.

Comment: Angular 10 is worse! @hoang

Comment: @DavidGenger I am still working on Angular 9 for new project and some are Angular 4 for maintaining only. How worse is it? I really appreciate if you could update new solution if u have for Angular 10.

Comment: It's just taking very long I have no workaround yet. @hoang

Comment: There is a Github issue with a response from the Angular team that we might get some improvements to JIT compiler for Angular 11 (released within the next 2-3 months) but no word for AOT compiler

Answer (score 3):

I see only temporary half-solutions so I am going to provide more ligh on this matter.

I met these problems on few projects and it is probably due to how your app is written.
In my case there were problems with compiling scss and wrong NgModules management. Unfortunately you cannot show us whole application I guess.

I recommend a few things:

- Use webpack-bundle-analyzer and fix everything you will find thanks to this tool (it is possible you compile things you have there by accident or that you don´t need at all).
- Check your global styles. It is important how you import those styles, you have to AVOID duplicities of imported styles and circular dependencies. It is easy to miss that you are importing scss file that import another scss file and so on. I recommend to have only ONE file with imports (order of imports matters), then it is easy to debug the compile time of those styles. And in components you will never import this file that imports everything but only the styles/mixis you really need.
- Check what libraries/styles/scripts you added in angular.json in scripts, styles and stylePreprocessorOptions. Everything like that can slow the build time.
- Maybe you want to try dart sass over node sass? If so, install fibbers, uninstall node-sass and try to build.
- Check your NgModules. Are all of them imported correctly? Again look into result javascript bundle. Aren´t there any duplicities you want to avoid in the result bundle?
- I recommend to reduce your app only on the core AppModule and maybe styles... then add (or even remove styles or other things) gradually more things... and build. You will debug the problem this way, find the problem and resolve it.

Things like that happen when the application grows and noone pays attention to this, but many of those things are easily to miss. People then say that Angular is bad and move to other libraries/frameworks, but it is just our misunderstanding of Angular genius and complexity that limits us. Good luck! :-)

Comment: There is already an open issue for Angular. 9.0.7 the build times were lower. With anything above 9.0.7, the build times shot up.https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36414

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in your angular configuration is similar to as below

```
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss",
      "prefix": "cfs"
    },
```

I think `styleext` changed to `style` in `angular 9`

there might be some configuration issue, in angular, the compiler time should be drastically reduced.

you can look into this PR, i migrated and it wend well
https://github.com/aniruddhadas9/candifood-ui/pull/15

Comment: Hello, Thanks for replying, i did these changes but not affected to compiling time:(